# Using the Paypal Mobile SDK UI in the REST API

Tags: paypal

I was trying you the Paypal Rest Api here: https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal

In the third step, a link is given which takes you to the login screen of paypal. The link looks like this: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2AV07917JJ307845R

I saw the login screen in the ios mobile SDK here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK, which has a really good UI. Is there some way in which the UI of the Mobile SDK can be used in the REST API?

Comment: iOS and web has different flows for checkout but check out https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/identity/button/ and https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/ for customizing web UI experience for the web.

Answer (score 0):

The example in the first (and second) links are for building a web app on top of the REST SDK. The good news is that the Mobile SDKs are also built on top of the REST API.

However, the examples for mobile are not as complete. But there is a [mobile backend example app in the Python SDK](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend). It should play nicely with the [payment verification step](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) or [capturing an authorization](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/capture-payment/#capture-the-payment). [Authorizations can be created on iOS](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md) by setting `payment.intent = PayPalPaymentIntentAuthorize`.